# React Router v6.4.5, redirect on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

Looking for some help in regards to redirecting. Below are the code snippets.

index.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([

  {
    //set App as root element...
    path: "/",
    loader: () => {

    },
    element: <App/>,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage/>,

    //set routes for child elements...
    children: [
      {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Home/>
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About/>,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage/>
      },  
      {
        path: "/blog",
       element: <Blog/>,
       errorElement: <ErrorPage/>
      },
      {
        path: "/services",
        element: <Services/>,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage/>
      }

    ]
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    {/* <App /> */}
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Outlet, redirect, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./views/Home";


function App() {

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <Outlet/> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

All I want to do is have the page redirect from 'localhost:3000/' when the page loads './' as the root to 'localhost:3000/home' so I can render the applications home page. Where I am using an outlet I want it to render there and have the navbar render at all times. I don't see an option in the docs for createBrowserRouter for a redirect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can render a redirect from `"/"` to `"/home"` via the [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component and the `replace` prop.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    //set App as root element...
    path: "/",
    loader: () => { ... },
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,

    //set routes for child elements...
    children: [
      {
        index: true, // <-- match on parent, i.e. "/"
        element: <Navigate to="/home" replace /> // <-- redirect
      },
      {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />
      },  
      {
        path: "/blog",
       element: <Blog />,
       errorElement: <ErrorPage />
      },
      {
        path: "/services",
        element: <Services />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I was scouring the documentation for a solution, but wasn't aware that there is an index option for the children element in the createBrowserRouter options. Although, what does the index option actually do here. I've looked at the documentation to help me understand. I checked this out, [link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/index-search-param)Index Query Param , but it's still confusing.

Comment: @rwright94 [Index routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#index-routes) match along with and render their element into their parent route's outlet.

Comment: Tyvm! Guess I wasn't looking far enough down the documentation.